# Limit of a sum and two ways yielding two answers

Tags: algebra-precalculus, limits, summation

$$\lim_ {n\to \infty} \sum_{r=0}^n \frac{1}{(2r+1)(2r+3)(2r+2)}$$

Now, what I did here was to first break up the general term of the sum using partial fractions, yielding

$$ \frac{1}{(2r+1)(2r+2)(2r+3)}=\frac{1}{2}( \frac{1}{2r+1} +\frac{1}{2r+3} - \frac{1}{r+1} )$$

Now, if I were to telescope this sum without first expanding the sums in the limit, I get the answer as

$$\lim_ {n\to \infty} \sum_{r=0}^n \frac{1}{(2r+1)(2r+3)(2r+2)} = (2ln2 -1) $$

But if I were to do it like this

$$ 2 \sum_{r=0}^\infty \frac{1}{(2r+1)(2r+2)(2r+3)}= \sum_{r=0}^\infty \frac{1}{2r+1} +\frac{1}{2r+3} - \frac{1}{r+1} $$

and then expand the sums of each term, getting

$$\lim_ {n\to \infty} \sum_{r=0}^n \frac{1}{(2r+1)(2r+3)(2r+2)}=\frac{1}{2}( (\frac{1}{1}+ \frac{1}{3} +\cdots)+ (\frac{1}{3} +\frac{1}{5} +\cdots ) - (\frac{1}{1} +\frac{1}{2} +\cdots))  $$

Here, we can see that the terms we get from expanding the sum of the term $ \frac{1}{2r+1}$ get cancelled due to the negatives from the sum of term $\frac{1}{r+1}$ thus we get the sum equal to

$$\frac{1}{2} ( -\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3} -\frac{1}{4} +\cdots )$$ which is equal to $$( \frac{ ln2-1}{2})$$

Now this is obviously wrong and i think what's wrong with this method is that if we just see the expansions per  value of r ,it has another convergence than this expansion which might be causing the problems,but any help and a push in the right direction will help

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_series_theorem

Comment: @JMoravitz the series $\sum_{j=0}^\infty\frac{1}{(2j+1)(2j+2)(2j+3)}$ is absolutely convergent though, and so it should also be unconditionally convergent

Comment: @Lorago But the three sums in the incorrect method don't converge, so the sum depends on the order of those elements.